# Fill parent div with a component and scroll if needed - ng pdf viewer

Tags: html, css, angular, layout, pdf-viewer

I am trying to use the `ng-pdf-viewer` library to embed a component with a PDF into a web-page (angular). I have a container div, that I want to be the parent of the pdf viewer. It's dimensions are not fixed (it's not a fixed pixel value, the size of the container depends on the size of the screen / other elements - it fills the space).
My goal is to have the pdf viewer be exactly the size of the container and have a scroll for long pdfs within that container (the `bordered-content` div, blue in the screenshots).

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="bordered-content flex-fill" style="background-color: blue">
      <div class="pdf-viewer-wrapper">
        <pdf-viewer [src]="'pdf-link'"
                    fit-to-page="true">
        </pdf-viewer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the css:

```
.bordered-content {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid $light-color;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.pdf-viewer-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}
```

However, with this setup, the pdf-viewer wrapper doesn't seem to obey the `height: 100%` rule and just never shows the scroll - instead it overflows the container for as many pages as there are in the pdf.

If I change the `pdf-viewer-wrapper` class to :

```
.pdf-viewer-wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: red;
}
```

it suddenly starts listening to the `height` rule and the scroll is there. The pdf-viewer however is limited to 600px , not to the height of the parent which is not ideal.

[image: Screenshot of pdf viewer limited to 600px]

Can you please explain to me why it's working for a fixed number of pixels for height and not for 100% ? And how to fix it?